# Clicking the copy button, JavaScript id just copy the first data from database and I'm unable to copy others data

Tags: javascript, database, loops

I'm working on a self project where I have to retrieve my database data (e.g. names which are unique) and in the website, these names are listed. What I'm trying to do is if user click the name there appear popup with the user info and there is click button. After clicking the click button user can copy the info. But what problem is after clicking the copy button JavaScript id just copy the first data from database and I'm unable to copy others data. These data are taken from the database using forloop.

```
{% for twenty in twenty %}

    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button"
                       data-toggle="dropdown"
                       aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                        {{ twenty.name }}
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <div class="copy">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8">
                                <input type="text" value="{{ twenty.detail }}" id="myInput1">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <button onclick="myFunction1()">Copy</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </li>

{% endfor %}

<h3><a href="{% url 'movielink: movie_list_view_all' twenties.slug %}">View All</a></h3>

{% block script %}

    <script>
        function myFunction1() {
                var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput1");
                copyText.select();
                copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
                document.execCommand("copy");
                alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
            }
    </script>

{% endblock script %}
```

Comment: I think your problem is that the myInput1 is an id in a loop. and so it's not unique.
Let me have a crack at this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. So the id is different each time. You might have an id, or you might need to introduce a counter. It's been a while since I did what I think is twig/php

```
 {% for twenty in twenty %}

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button"
                           data-toggle="dropdown"
                           aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            {{ twenty.name }}
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                        <div class="copy">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-8">
                                    <input type="text" value="{{ twenty.detail }}" id="myInput{{ twenty.id }}">
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <button onclick="myFunction1('myInput{{ twenty.id }}')">Copy</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>

    {% endfor %}


{% block script %}

    <script>
        function myFunction1(id) {
                var copyText = document.getElementById(id);
                copyText.select();
                copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999);
                document.execCommand("copy");
                alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.value);
            }
    </script>

{% endblock script %}
```

Comment: @SujanDangal Hi if it works can you give it a tick. Just so you approve the answer.